# Wrong accuracy validation set

Tags: tensorflow, validation, keras, loss

I have a model for identification object by spectrum

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 64, input_shape=(train_generator.get_half_spec_size(160000),  1),  kernel_size = 20, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool1D(strides=5))


model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It seems that I have strange thing with 'accuracy' metric. First of all, almost in all epoches I have 0.66 accuracy for train set and 0.99 for validation set.

Okay. Than when model has learned - I just took one sample and check if validation is correct on sample. The validation was not correct (there were 1 but predicted 0), but answer of evaluate was

```
[2.060739278793335, 1.0]
```

so big loss ( expectingly ) and wrong accuracy (1.0)

Then I took another sample and predicted again. answer of 'evaluate' was

```
[0.18439120054244995, 1.0]
```

so correct loss and accuracy now (and in fact the prediction of model was correct).

My suggestion is that 'accuracy' metrics works wrong there. Or where there is a mistake?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your labels?

Comment: it just a 0 or 1 one dimensional vector

Comment: In that case you need to set your model up for a binary classifier. Change final dense nodes to 1, activation sigmoid, and loss binary cross entropy

Comment: I don't thinks that's the case. I have a two-class task not two labels. And sum of proba must be equal to 1. So softmax is the right case

Comment: But won't your loss function be comparing a single scalar with an array of length 2? Maybe you need to one-hot encode your labels so they are an array of length two?

Comment: Yep, I already though that's that may be the case, but for example digit recognition on MNIST works well even without hot encoding (and softmax output). Probably I don't understand something